# Mapping over nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to map over a nested object in react and pass the values as props to a component to render. Any suggestions of how to map it or changes to the object structure would be appreciated.

**My Object:**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "body":"first obj",
      "nested":[{  
         "id":3,
         "body":"nested obj",
         "nested":null
      }]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "body":"second obj",
      "nested":null
   }
]
```

I would like to pass each object as `props` to a component and the same has to be done with the nested object as well.

**Component:**

```
<Foo key = {id} body = {body}/>
```

**Render:**

```
<Foo/> // id 1
    <Foo/> // id 3
<Foo/> // id 2
```

I want to achieve the structure as shown above.

Comment: is Foo with id 2 has extra tab?

Comment: The JSON is just an example. Foo with id 2 could have extra and Foo with id 3 could have extra too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested maps with React.Fragment to avoid extra divs.

```
nestedObj.map(({ id, body, nested }) =>
   <React.Fragment>
       <Foo id={id} body={body}
       {nested.map(({id, body}) => <Foo id={id} body={body} />)}
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

If you have more nested arrays i would create flat array first and then simply do map over flat array.

```
const getFlatArray = nested => {
  if(!nested) return [];
  let output = [];
  nested.forEach(item => {
    output = [...output, item, ...getFlatArray(item.nested)];
  })
    return output;
}

 const flatArray = getFlatArray(nestedObj);

 return <React.Fragment>
   {flatArray.map(({id, body}) => <Foo id={id} body={body} />)}
 </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Sounds good but what if {nested.map(({id, body}) => <Foo id={id} body={body} />)} has a nested object to it?

Comment: Would it make it easy to render if I had an array of objects with the `nested` field pointing to `id` of the object in the array?

Comment: i would make flat array first and then simply map over it. let me try to get you that code.

Answer (score -1):

To `map` into a nested array I suggest using recursion:

```
{
  function createFoos(ele) {
    const a = ele.map(function(({id, body})){
      return <Foo key={id} body={body}/>;
    });
    return ele.nested ? a.concat(createFoos(ele.nested)) : a;
  }

  createFoos(arr);
}
```